# Symfony2 embedded forms using one class

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to use an Embedded form without using a separated class for it?
The reason is I've got a lot of form classes already, which most of the time contain a single field, so I wonder if it is possible to define embedded forms inline.

So normally we have something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('key', new KeyType())            
    ;
}
```

The documentation says that I have to create a class for the `key` field, `KeyType` for example, where I would set up the form builder for the embedded form. But I would like to, instead of creating the class `KeyType`, define the fields inline, in the same class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add(
            $builder->create('key')
                ->add('someField', 'text')
                ->add('otherField', 'checkbox')
        )       
    ;
}
```